# Add SKSpriteNode using space bar in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit

i'm using a basic Breakout game frame work. I would like to add balls using the space bar. I have got it to a point where the balls appear but am failing to apply impulse so they bounce around. I would also like them to have a life span of x number of seconds. Here is the relevant compressed part of the code.

Im using Xcode 9 for OSX/macOS not iOS swift 4 10.13.2

```
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        let keyEvent = event.characters
        if keyEvent == " "{print("space bar")

            // Create sprite
            let myBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "greenball")
            myBall.zPosition = 1
            myBall.xScale = 1
            myBall.yScale = 1

            // Determine where to spawn the ball along the Y axis
            let actualY:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(624))-312.0

            // Position the ball
            myBall.position = CGPoint(x: 460.0, y: actualY)

            // Determine speed of the ball
            let actualDuration:CGFloat = 4.0

            myBall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
            myBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
            myBall.physicsBody?.friction = 1
            myBall.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
            myBall.physicsBody?.mass = 0.0035744346678257

            addChild(myBall)

            myBall.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 300.0, dy: -300.0))//<--this does not fore ??
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: hi the question why the applyImpulse isn't working? . And how do i set the life span of the balls.thankyou

Comment: You forgot to create the physics body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to always remember to create a physics body.  I would recommend using ! instead of ? when you are dealing with optionals.  Use ? only when you expect your result to be nil,  otherwise you want your program to crash during debugging so that you know you have an error.

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    let keyEvent = event.characters
    if keyEvent == " "{print("space bar")

        // Create sprite
        let myBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "greenball")
        myBall.zPosition = 1
        myBall.xScale = 1
        myBall.yScale = 1

        // Determine where to spawn the ball along the Y axis
        let actualY:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(624))-312.0

        // Position the ball
        myBall.position = CGPoint(x: 460.0, y: actualY)

        // Determine speed of the ball
        let actualDuration:CGFloat = 4.0
        myBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:myBall.size.width /2 )
        myBall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
        myBall.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
        myBall.physicsBody!.friction = 1
        myBall.physicsBody!.restitution = 1
        myBall.physicsBody!.mass = 0.0035744346678257

        addChild(myBall)

        myBall.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 300.0, dy: -300.0))//<--this does not fore ??
    }
}
```

If you decide you do not want to be lazy, and want to write cleaner code, then I recommend doing `if let` or `guard let`

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    let keyEvent = event.characters
    if keyEvent == " "{
        print("space bar")

        // Create sprite
        let myBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "greenball")
        myBall.zPosition = 1
        myBall.xScale = 1
        myBall.yScale = 1

        // Determine where to spawn the ball along the Y axis
        let actualY:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(624))-312.0

        // Position the ball
        myBall.position = CGPoint(x: 460.0, y: actualY)

        // Determine speed of the ball
        let actualDuration:CGFloat = 4.0
        if let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:myBall.size.width/1)
        {
            physicsBody.isDynamic = true
            physicsBody.affectedByGravity = true
            physicsBody.friction = 1
            physicsBody.restitution = 1
            physicsBody.mass = 0.0035744346678257 //<-- You really shouldnt mess with this unless you know what you are doing with mass
            myBall.physicsBody = physicsBody
        }
        addChild(myBall)

        myBall.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 300.0, dy: -300.0))//<--this does not fore ??
    }
}
```